# How to check if spark actually parallelizes the job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I wonder how can I check in Intellij Idea that `sc.parallelize` actually parallelizes the job? For example, how can I see that

```
val list = Range(0, 100000, 1)
val dist_list = sc.parallelize(list)
println(dist_list.reduce((x,y) => x + y)
```

really parallelizes and work faster , than just `list.reduce((x,y) => x + y)`? Of course I can just measure the time of execution but I wonder if there are clear tools to do that?

Comment: if you work locally (no cluster), you could just check your cpu usage (should utilize more than 1 core), but better check Spark UI, but you need some intermediate knowledge on Spark to fully understand the information shown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Spark always parallelizes the work, just to make sure you can run the following code (on master `local[*]`):

```scala
val list = Range(0, 100000, 1)
val dist_list = sc.parallelize(list)
dist_list.foreachPartition(_ => println("thread: " + Thread.currentThread.getName))
```

You should see multiple threads in the output.

2. As for tools, you can try [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) (benchmarks) or [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) (performance monitoring). And don't forget about Spark UI as it provides a lot of information regarding the performance of Spark.